Animated series where a disease turns people into zombie-like creatures
I watched this one when I was a kid like 10 years ago.
There is a disease or infection that makes people transform into zombie like creatures. Our main group gets ability to turn into those creatures while not losing their consciousness. They gain this ability by consuming a pill or injecting a serum developed by father of the main character. Also these creatures our guys turn into got their own names.
Main characters name starting with a D as I remember. Something like Desmond or David. His creature’s name also starts with a D.
I watched this animation series around 2010 - 2013.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you watch this?  Television or online?  What country?
